# can not open .cshrc after modifying

Tags: linux, redhat, csh

I am on a RedHat csh.
I just modified `~/.cshrc` with a wrong path and resulting in an `syntax-error`.
my shell just not recognize `ls` or `gedit`. So, when I again try to modify, it is not again opening with `gedit ~/.cshrc`.

When I boot the system it is not starting the profile.
I Have the root access and root profile is fine. Can I edit it from root. 
Please help me to remove last two lines i have added to `/.cshrc`, using root-profile so that it works normal as previous.

thanks.

Comment: You could just rename it using `mv`.

Comment: sorry! bt i dont understand. please explain a bit. I need the whole .cshrc profile except the last two lines.

Comment: You can rename your `.cshrc` file so that it is no longer executed.  Then start a new shell, and everything should be fine. YOu can edit the file and then rename it back to `.cshrc`.

Comment: it it possible to edit it from root profile .!? @larsks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to edit it from the root account.  When you log in as root, do you get a graphical environment or are you at the console?  If graphical, you can use `gedit /home/<username>/.cshrc`.  Replace `<username>` with the name of the user that is having the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your `PATH` isn't getting set properly due to the `syntax-error` in your `.cshrc` (assumption since you mention `ls` isn't working).  Try the following from your shell:

```
 echo $PATH
```

`echo` is a built-in and should always work.  If it returns nothing, is empty, or doesn't include a list of paths similar to `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc ... then your path is indeed incorrect.  Use the full path to `gedit` on the command line like:

```
/usr/bin/gedit ~/.cshrc
```